# Android - Unable to get the gps location on the emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, gps

i'm tring to use the gps on the android emulator, i've the following code:

```
public class NL extends Activity {

 private LocationManager locmgr = null;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nl);

        locmgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria crit = new Criteria();
        crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String provider = locmgr.getBestProvider(crit, true);
        Location loc = locmgr.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(this, "Lon: " + Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()) + " Lat: " + Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        msg.show();
    }
}
```

i've added the following line at the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and i've set the gps location with the DDMS method and either with the geo fix method, but when i run the code, i get a NullPointerExeption at the Toast line, probably cause loc is null.

I don't understand where the error is... can you help me please?

---

UPDATE!

Thanks for your help, now i use the following code and i don't get any error, but it doesn't run the code inside onChangeLocation... it doesn't run the Toast and don't return any message in the log!

```
 public class NL extends Activity {

        private LocationManager locmgr = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.nl);

            locmgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

         // Define a listener that responds to location updates
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
                  // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                    Log.i("NOTIFICATION","onLocationChenged Triggered");

                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(NetworkLocator.this, "Lon: " + Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()) + " Lat: " + Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    msg.show();
                }

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
              };

            // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
            locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you verify if *locmgr.getBestProvider* actually returns "gps"? anyway, you should definitely implement a *LocationListener* and pass it to LocationManager with *requestLocationUpdates()*

Comment: the getBestProvider return "gps". have i to add a locationlistener even if i try to get the locatio with lastKnownLocation? thanks for your help

Comment: @Marco Faion Please keep ur answers updated... I answered already once to you and you didn't give any feedback on the answer! > `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591765/android-sqlite-database-method-undefined-fot-type/4591843#4591843`

Comment: hello Macro did u got the solution or not?

Comment: thanks for your help, qith requestLocationUpdates the application run fine, but i think that the "onLocationChange is never triggered... not sure if this is because i've set to 0 the time and distance parameters: locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

Comment: put a Log output to the `onLocationChange` and look in Logcat if something get printed...

Comment: i've followed your suggestion, the onLocationChanged never trigger!

Comment: FOUND THE SOLUTION: LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER is WRONG. correction: LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FOUND THE SOLUTION:

LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER is WRONG.

correction: LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

Comment: In my experience the emulator does not appear to respond to location changes sent via DDMS when the provider is set to NETWORK_PROVIDER, but will when it is set to GPS_PROVIDER as you have noted. This looks like a limitation in the emulator to me, or at least a behaviour that it not obvious.

Answer (score 9):

Emulator just doesn't have any location at the beginning. According to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29), 'getLastKnownLocation' method can return *null*, so it is ok. In that case you should wait for location updates (you can user requestLocationUpdates method from LocationManager). You can trigger location update on emulator's gps module by following command:

```
adb -e emu geo fix 50 50
```

Answer (score 1):

if all you what you described is done than maybe you are not probably not ur gps is on in emulator.go to setting:->Location and Security:->and use gps satelites should be checked

---

**edited**:ithink you have to use location manager without criteria type.

---

---

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

loc=mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

------than try to get long. and lat.

Comment: the "use gps satelites" is checked

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your emulated device is actually supporting GPS?
I think there was an extra option for this...

This may help too:

> Thanks! To all: You can change the Build Target for your project any time in Eclipse: Right-click the project in Package Explorer, select Properties > Android and then check 'Google API' for Project Target. -- Developers working with non-English culture settings might notice that pressing the Send button in Location Controls does not send a new location to the Android emulator. It's fixed with the upcoming release 7 of the SDK tools; for a quick fix you can change your locale to 'en'. (See code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=915 for details.) – Patrick de Kleijn

source: [GPS on emulator doesn't get the geo fix - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896889/gps-on-emulator-doesnt-get-the-geo-fix-android)