# How to push a location to emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to set a point as current location in emulator? I use location controls in DDMS, but It doesn't work! Any body know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You tried this way ah: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-set-location-emulator

Comment: 0_0, some links are blocked in china, maythe link www.helloandroid.com is included!!!

Comment: Ok, Follow the Steps, 1. go to your android/tools directory, and launch the DDMS tool
2. select the Emulator Control Tab
3. fill the Location Controls fields with the longitude and latitude values
4.press the Send button

Comment: I tried DDMS's location control and telnet, but both are failed!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class NL extends Activity {

    private LocationManager locmgr = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nl);

        locmgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

     // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
              // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                Log.i("NOTIFICATION","onLocationChenged Triggered");

                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(NetworkLocator.this, "Lon: " + Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()) + " Lat: " + Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                msg.show();
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
          };

        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }
}
```

Reffered from [Android - Unable to get the gps location on the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745670/android-unable-to-get-the-gps-location-on-the-emulator)