# Why doesn't GeoLocation work on android?

Tags: android, html, mobile, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

To this date my android phone (and googles android emulator AVD/SDK) doesn't work with w3c geolocation API from web pages ex.

the example at : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

or alternative : http://ocupado.eu/info

" The W3C Geolocation API is also supported by Opera Mobile 10.1 — available for Android and Symbian devices (S60 generations 3 & 5) since November 24, 2010."

according to this : link >> wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API

I have checked every setting regarding Location in the phone but nothing loads (even if the map doesn't load from google maps the coordinates should load)... but no.

Any ideas? anyone have an Android that works with these basic web geolocation pages?

Is there any "extra code" required to get it to work with android or is it a no go?

/

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4745907/1426565

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I think that is only regarding the GPS function. Google location service that is used to look up your position also use ip or wifi access points, as a location source, so shouldn't it still send a result back even in the emulator, if is supported?