# get my current position using Trigger.io and Android emulator

Tags: android, geolocation, trigger.io, forge

i tried to execute som code using Trigger.io to get my current position
i added the module [geolocation](https://toolkit-local.com:38394/#apps/6ad19d383d6211e3beee12313b0234c0/browseModuleDetails/geolocation/v2.0) .
here's my script code :

```
      $( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#map-page", function() {
      forge.logging.log('... Initializing map');
      forge.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {


        forge.logging.log('Set current position:');
        forge.logging.log(position.coords);

        forge.logging.log('Created map ...');
      });
  forge.logging.log('out ...');
       });
```

i run it on forge and it STOPPED on

... Initializing map

out ...
IT DIDN'T GIVE ME A RESULT

PS : on main code i just add jquery-mobile TAGs and

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">

        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Should work fine on a real android device. For the emulator you have to follow the instruction here to give it a location: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4745907/725359

Comment: i use jquery mobile to implement my app so i can't find the good answer.