# Android GPS cannot display my location and Map nearby in the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps, android-manifest

when running on my Android GPS application on application

why I cannot load the Google Map content even i have given the geo fix location , MapAPI , telnet and so on ?

some time gray checkers , sometimes goes blank..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have selected the proper Build target. Right click on your project. Go to properties and then select Android. Then select one of the Google APIs instead of Android.

This is also answered here:

[GPS on emulator doesn't get the geo fix - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896889/gps-on-emulator-doesnt-get-the-geo-fix-android)